Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException while ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC app trying to connect with IdentityServer4 App in IIS
We are migrating our projects from .NET 6.0 to .NET 8.0, where I am getting this error.
We have one ASP.NET Core MVC application which is trying to connect to the IdentityServer4 application for authentication.
When I have migrated to .NET 8.0, it is working successfully on local. But once I deploy it to IIS, it throwing this error:

An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {f203edca-73bf-4b5f-ae0a-3d0a2c304ab4} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
2024-06-07 16:46:16.191 +05:30 [ERR] Unable to fetch automatic login credentials. Redirecting to login page.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Update -1:
Below configuration at Client side.
ConfigureServices():
  services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = 
  false).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
  services.AddSession();

  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy("UserPermission",
    policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new 
    UserPermissionAuthorization()));
  });

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme =   CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
options.Cookie.Name = 
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(loginExpiryinSeconds);
options.SlidingExpiration = false;
}).AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
options.ClientId = axiClientId;
options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.Authority = idServerUrl;
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
options.SaveTokens = true;
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
options.Scope.Clear();
options.Scope.Add("openid");
options.Scope.Add("profile");
});

services.AddHsts(options =>
{
options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
});

services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryFieldname";
options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";
options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
});

Configure():
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Xss-Protection", "1; mode=block");
context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies", "none");
await next();
});
app.UseSession();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax });
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
       
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self' http://code.jquery.com http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com http://localhost:*; script-src 'self' http://code.jquery.com http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com http://localhost:*; style-src 'self' http://code.jquery.com http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; font-src 'self' http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; img-src 'self' http://www.w3.org/ http://code.jquery.com; frame-src 'self'");

await next();
});


could you try to clear browser cache and cookie? set iis app pool to load user profile to "true". could you share where and how you are storing the key? could you share your web.config file? Make sure iis app pool has enough permission to read the key.

Yes, I tried to clear browser cache and cookie. The iis app pool is with load user profile to "true". I will provide the config file here. FYI: It is working properly with .Net 6.0, locally as well as with IIS.

This would require a session of some kind.  Usually there is no session before login so login does not require antiforgery token.  If a session has begun and if this is thrown during login a new session should begin (else you have a session-fixation vulnerability) so your antiforgery token might be tied to the old session?  (don't include anti-forgery with login form...)

You might also include front-end code here... are you reading the hidden field to set the header?  (Usually you'd set options.headerName when sending a JS request without formData() object...)

There is no JS code while sending the request in my scenario. One client which is MVC application sending a request to another identityServer4 app, both are in .Net 8.0.

try to add iis app pool user or iis user to access  key ring directory. try to use different key ring location for different  environments

You'll need to remove "options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";" bit there.   That's only needed if sending the CSRF token as a custom header.  If using a standard form it'll be included as a hidden field in the form.  (You won't need to customize any options in that case... you can remove all those options)

since this is a decryption error it could also be caused by a load balancer.  (different servers would have different keys... if the GET gets the antiforgery token and the POST ends up at another server, you might see this kind of error.  Use "sticky sessions".)

likewise if the MVC application is on one server and the identityServer4 is on another.  (if the GET is to MVC app server, and the POST goes to identity server, that's not going to work.  The whole point of it is to prevent that from happening.)

you typically get that error whe you have not configure the data protection API, i did blog some about it here https://nestenius.se/2024/02/22/persisting-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault/
